# FRITZ!Box DynDNS w/ dynv6.com not updating prefix

Tags: ipv6, dynamic-dns, dsl

I can configure dynv6.com in my FRITZ!Box with german tutorial from here:

[fritz!box configuration](https://www.heise.de/select/ct/2020/11/2009415254180634543)

as soon as my router gets a new prefix in the night I cannot access my fritz!box and exposed host anymore.

This is the connection string used:

```
http://dynv6.com/api/update?hostname=<domain>&token=<username>&ipv4=auto http://dynv6.com/api/update?hostname=<domain>&token=<username>&ipv6=auto&ipv6prefix=2003:00ee:87
```

The dynv6.com information says:

```
Address/Prefix
79.227.186.145
2003:ee:8733:a800:5495:3aa4:9afb:d497
Last update
12 minutes ago
```

My question is: is the ipv6 prefix length really `/64` with telekom vectoring DSL?

**Update**: I changed ipv6 prefix to `/40` and the router and exposed host is pinging! Although Fritzbox says:

```
IPv6-Status: Fehler
```

Some time later...
No ping6 or ping possible!

It seems to me: FRITZ!Box is not updating the prefix on dynv6.com

Any ideas?

This is my current connection string - ping6 from router and exposed host working fine:

```
http://dynv6.com/api/update?hostname=<domain>&token=<key>&ipv4=auto http://dynv6.com/api/update?hostname=<domain>&token=<key>&ipv6=2003:ee:870b:db00:f08b:19f9:5d55:3b18&ipv6prefix=2003:00ee:870b:db00::
```

Mentioning the two colons at the end of the ipv6prefix!

Works until I get:

```
From leder-ryzen-home.fritz.box (2003:ee:870e:b000:f08b:19f9:5d55:3b18) icmp_seq=28 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

---

Hey super users out there:
I do not get ipv6 w/ dynv6.com, wieistmeineip.de, IPv6 Subnet Calculator
and fritz!box exposed host running!

Anybody out there who can step by step advise or give tutorial link other than the mentioned one?

---

I have tried `/56` length prefix for fritzbox and `/64` length prefix for exposed host: to no avail!

Comment: The prefix length for a regular IPv6 network is usually 64 bits. Your ISP will usually give a larger lease (shorter prefix), so your router can create more subnets (or do Prefix Delegation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard that `dynv6.com` is no good!

I wanted to connect my smartphone to my desktop via ssh, so I did this:

- introduced VPN configuration on smartphone to the Fritz!Box 7590
- connected my smartphone via VPN
- ssh'ed to the local IP address of my desktop
- Voila! Mission accompished w/o dynv6.com for Fritz!Box